# Help needed for s7graphview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, s7graphview

If anyone have used s7graphview for plotting the graph then I want to know where to do changes in the code for maintaining the incremental value of the values that is been plot on the x-axis. Currently it maintains according to the count of array being return to it. I want to maintain incremental gap of 5 units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace in `drawRect:` of `S7GraphView` class next lines (~220 line in S7GraphView.m):

```
if (xValuesCount > 5)
{       
    NSUInteger stepCount = 5;
    NSUInteger count = xValuesCount - 1;

    for (NSUInteger i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        if (count % i == 0) {
            stepCount = i;
        }
    }

    step = xValuesCount / stepCount;
    maxStep = stepCount + 1;
}
else
{       
    step = 1;
    maxStep = xValuesCount;
}
```

with **this code**:

```
if (xValuesCount > 5)
{       
    NSUInteger stepCount = 5 - 1;

    step = xValuesCount / stepCount;
    maxStep = stepCount + 1;
}
else
{       
    step = 1;
    maxStep = xValuesCount;
}
```

On DemoS7GraphView project from [s7graph google code page](http://code.google.com/p/s7graphview/downloads/list) it gives me next result:
[image: result from code changing]

Hope it helps.